# Highcharter: chart.hide is not a function

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to replace the chart rendered with another chart using Highcharts, using Highcharter in R:

```
test_code <- JS("
function toggleSeries_test() {
  var chart1 = Highcharts.charts[0]; 
  var chart2 = Highcharts.charts[1]; 
  if (chart1.visible) {
    chart1.hide();
    chart2.show();
  } else {
    chart2.hide();
    chart1.show();
    }
  }

document.getElementById('toggleButton_test').addEventListener('click', toggleSeries_test);
")
```

But I'm getting an error: `chart2.hide is not a function`

Is this due to a syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no `hide` or `show` functions, nor is the `visible` property ever defined, unless you define it yourself. If ever interested, here's the [full documetation](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart) for the `Chart` instances, with all properties and methods.

The usual way charts are hidden (not to be disposed of) is by using CSS. Here's a very basic set of functions to show, hide and enquire visibility:

```js
function toggleSeries_test() {
  var chart1 = Highcharts.charts[0]; 
  var chart2 = Highcharts.charts[1]; 
  if (isChartVisible(chart1)) {
    hideChart(chart1);
    showChart(chart2);
  } else {
    hideChart(chart2);
    showChart(chart1);
    }
  }

  function isChartVisible(chart){
     return chart.container.style.display !== 'none';
  }

  function showChart(chart){
     return chart.container.style.display = '';
  }

  function hideChart(chart){
     return chart.container.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

Of course, all this goes inside inside the `JS` call, with the event listener.

This is untested because there isn't the full code here; there are also other possibilities but my doubts are mainly related by the way you manage to hide the second chart initially. Please let me know.